# group objects based on their attribute values

Tags: php, data-structures, foreach

**This is what my data looks like**

```
array (size=2)


0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'name' => string 'A new event' (length=11)
      'start_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
      'end_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
      'subscription_start_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
      'subscription_end_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
      'capacity' => string '5' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'name' => string 'A new event 2' (length=13)
      'start_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
      'end_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
      'subscription_start_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
      'subscription_end_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
      'capacity' => string '5' (length=1)
```

Now see the `start_time` property in both objects.. I want to group all objects with same `start_time` so when I get data of like 100 objects like this I can loop through them and put all objects with same `start_time` in a single array of objects in an object...

I know it will be simple looping of foreach but its been so long since I have dealt with object grouping so its confusing for me now. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is what I ended up writing**
It works perfectly

```
$all_grouped_events = array_fill(0, sizeof($modelEvent->all_events)-1 , array());
            $current_time = $modelEvent->all_events[0]['start_time'];

            foreach ($modelEvent->all_events as $event) 
            {
                if($modelEvent->all_events[$count]['start_time'] == $current_time)
                {
                    array_push($all_grouped_events[$curr_count], $event);
                    $count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    $curr_count = $count;
                    $current_time = $modelEvent->all_events[$count]['start_time'];
                    array_push($all_grouped_events[$curr_count], $event);
                    $count++;
                }
            }
```

First line of the code is very important. `array_push` expects an array into which the value should be pushed so if we are creating an empty array and are pushing values in it it wont work because we would be accessing undefined indexes so the first line of the code initializes the array with all indexes (static) and pushes an array at every indexes.

**This is what the required data looks like and what I wanted**

```
array (size=2)


0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'name' => string 'A new event 3' (length=13)
          'start_time' => string '2014' (length=4)
          'end_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'subscription_start_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'subscription_end_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'capacity' => string '5' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'name' => string 'A new event' (length=11)
          'start_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'end_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'subscription_start_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'subscription_end_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'capacity' => string '5' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=6)
          'name' => string 'A new event 2' (length=13)
          'start_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'end_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'subscription_start_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'subscription_end_time' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'capacity' => string '5' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
function groupBy($array, $key) {
    $groupedData = [];
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if ( ! array_key_exists($value[$key], $groupedData)) {
            $groupedData[$value[$key]] = [];
        }
        $groupedData[$value[$key]][] = $value;
    }
    return $groupedData;
}
```